# AI generation of animated 2D sprites

Tags: graphics, artificial-intelligence, sprite

I am developing a 2D top-down view game (more specifically, a Factorio mod rather than a stand-alone game). I need several models of buildings with simple animations indicating that they “do stuff” (here are some examples from the original game: https://cdn.factorio.com/assets/img/blog/fff-351-beacon-loop.mp4, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8SBp4SyvLc). Is there an AI image generator (like Midjourney or Dall-E) which can generate such animated sprites?

I'm ok with a paid subscription, but I would like the resulting images to be available without tedious legal limitations.

Comment: Hey buddy, if you found any useful tools, I appreciate it to share with me

Comment: @Abdoljabbar Haven't found anything so far. Will update this question if I do.